# Equal Distance between 8 boards to equal 14 ft

Tags: arithmetic

I know this is simple math.  But my board are not ending with the correct spacing for my pergola. Can someone help me figure this out. 8 boards to cover 14 ft . Do I start on one end and run them straight or start from the middle and work out from each side.

Comment: what are the dimensions of your boards?

Comment: As The Integrator alluded to, more details would be very helpful (necessary, even, I suspect).